# SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface using in-app billing

Tags: android

I'm getting a SecurityException when attempting to use the in-app billing library that Google offers. Here is the full exception:

```
07-05 15:56:47.783  26481-26481/com.andrewq.planets E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.andrewq.planets, PID: 26481
    java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.isBillingSupported(IInAppBillingService.java:208)
            at com.android.vending.billing.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected(IabHelper.java:227)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1101)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1118)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the IabHelper.java method with line 227:

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        if (mDisposed) return;
        logDebug("Billing service connected.");
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
        try {
            logDebug("Checking for in-app billing 3 support.");

            // check for in-app billing v3 support
            //**LINE 227**
            int response = mService.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);
            if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                if (listener != null) listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(response,
                                    "Error checking for billing v3 support."));

                // if in-app purchases aren't supported, neither are subscriptions.
                mSubscriptionsSupported = false;
                return; 
            }
            logDebug("In-app billing version 3 supported for " + packageName);

            // check for v3 subscriptions support
            response = mService.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, ITEM_TYPE_SUBS);
            if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                logDebug("Subscriptions AVAILABLE.");
                mSubscriptionsSupported = true;
            } else {
                logDebug("Subscriptions NOT AVAILABLE. Response: " + response);
            }

            mSetupDone = true;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(IABHELPER_REMOTE_EXCEPTION,
                                    "RemoteException while setting up in-app billing."));
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK, "Setup successful."));
        }
    }
};
```

And finally, here is the IInAppBillingService.java file where line 208 is:

```
@Override public int isBillingSupported(int apiVersion, java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String type) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
    android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    int _result;
    try {
        _data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
        _data.writeInt(apiVersion);
        _data.writeString(packageName);
        _data.writeString(type);
        mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_isBillingSupported, _data, _reply, 0);
        //**LINE 208**
        _reply.readException();
        _result = _reply.readInt();
    }
    finally {
        _reply.recycle();
        _data.recycle();
    }
    return _result;
}
```

Now this happens when I first launch my app. I got the exception after attaching a debugger to the process.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found my answer ( [here](http://blog.csdn.net/chenshufei2/article/details/8126108)), hope it solves yours. (It's in Chinese, but Chrome translated it.)
It had to do with the location of the .AIDL on the client side. It must be an exact duplicate of the .AIDL file in the server. And it must be placed in a package of the same name in the client's src folder.

[image]